# GetType not defined?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm developing a vb.net program with VS2008. In my case, dt_list is a instance member as List(of Single). When I wrote

```
dt_list = CType(ser2.Deserialize(r), dt_list.GetType())
```

VS2008 complains about "Type 'dt_list.GetType()' is not defined.".

Why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food dt_list is a instance member as List(of Single)

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely blind, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is not allowed is that the exact value of the type for `GetType()` must be determined at runtime.  The second parameter of [CType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) can only be an "expression that is legal within an As clause in a Dim statement, that is, the name of any data type, object, structure, class, or interface", for instance, `List(Of String)`, which can be determined at compile time.

The following is accordingly legal:

```
dt_list = CType(ser2.Deserialize(r), List(Of Single))
```

EDIT:

Casting to an arbitrary type, where the type is not known at compile time, is more involved, however.  The proposed answer to [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/fe14d396-bc35-4f98-851d-ce3c8663cd79) in the MSDN Forums shows one approach.  Though it's in C#, I will guess the same approach can be used in VB.NET as well.

Comment: So, to be short, GetType is a runtime routine while CType need a compile time parameter. Is there a way to do dynamic casting?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve by selecting the cast type at runtime?

You may be able to solve your problem with an interface.

```
Dim dt_list As IList = Ctype(ser2.Deserialize(r), IList)
```

This gives you access to all of the List members in [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx).